Xcode 16 / Reality Composer Pro 2 segmentation fault issue
After installing MacOS Sequoia, Xcode 16 & RealityComposer Pro 2 my Apple Vision Pro projects (worked perfectly with Xcode 15) started to give me Tool terminated by signal 'Segmentation fault: 11' error while compiling RealityKitContent assets. Is there any solution?
This happens only when I try to build project with .usdz models exported from Blender, but when I try with sample models from apple website it works nice with no errors.

There is an issue with the exported light (env_light) from blender. Just uncheck light when exporting your file from blender or and your usdz.file should work. Let me know if this was helpful!

or delete env_light with the text editor of your file.
